# DB migration using flyway on wildfly AS (domain mode) control

Tags: dns, wildfly, flyway

in my sample application, I have 5 SQL migration scripts (within war file).
I'm deploying the war file into wildfly 8.2 on main-server-group (consisting of two servers / instances).
The flyway.migrate() is called during the deployment (in the @PostConstruct of the application).
The issue observed is that the migration is started on both instances in parallel. The change of control is observed:

For example:

- SQL script 1 is applied by instance1
- SQL script 2 is applied by instance2
- SQL script 3 is applied by instance1
- SQL script 4 is applied by instance2
- SQL script 5 is applied by instance1

I would like to have a control: apply all SQL scripts (for example) on instance1 and let the instance2 waiting until DB migration is finished.

Can I achieve this easily?
Do I need some lock (for example entry in DB which will block the race condition)?

Thank you.

Comment: Why is the current behavior a problem?

Comment: I consider this as a higher risk that the migration will be finished successfully, especially in the case of large deployment of WAR file on multiple physical nodes. I see there a potential problem that each instance, which is migrating, has to evaluate the migration status (how many scripts were already applied). If the migration would be controlled by single instance, the migration can be done in one shot by this instance.

Comment: In practice neither of these have proven to be a problem so far...